# Converting a string (in array format) to an array in PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Is there an easy way to convert a string (which is already formatted like an array) to an array type in PHP (Laravel)?

Example:
`$string = "['user_id' => 123, 'merchant_id' => 456]"`

I would like to do something like this: `$userId = ((array) $string)['user_id'];`

I can of course parse this string and get the values that way but I want to know if there is a more elegant way (or if a function already exists for that).

Comment: https://www.php.net/eval - but beware: here be dragons.

Comment: @charliekelly Where do you get the string from?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo From an external provider, I receive the data in this format.

Comment: you could `str_replace` `=>` to `:`, then `str_replace` single quotes  to double quotes, then `[` to `{` and `]` to `}` and use `json_decode` unless your string contains other structures unlike the ones you posted.

Comment: Receiving such output from an external provider is really WRONG (on their side).. that is why we have JSON or XML outputs for APIs..

Comment: +1 on the above, this is potentially *very* unsafe. You might want to look into [runkit_sandbox()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it (maybe not the best, but it works): write the string as code in a file and include that file.

```
$string = "['user_id' => 123, 'merchant_id' => 456]";

file_put_contents('test','<?php $my_array='.$string.';?>');

require('test');

echo print_r($my_array,true);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 123
    [merchant_id] => 456
)
```

From there you have a normal array you can use.